# Make scrolling navbar stick to top of page after scrolling past

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

In bootstrap, I am trying to have a cover image and after scrolling past the navbar I want it to stick to the top of the page. I have scoured the internet and can't seem to find an answer that actually works. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found out using jQuery that I could target a specific class and use that to add classes to the class list.

```
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

var element_position = $('#scroll-to').offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = element_position;

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
      if (!navbar.classList.contains("fixed-top")) {
        navbar.classList.add("fixed-top");
      }
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("fixed-top");}
});
```